# Range of Excel cells have Concatenate formula and have no value in them. But when the range is selected, excel determines that there's values in them

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need some help with my excel formula. I have applied the concatenate formula to a range of cells in column D, wherein the formula takes the cell values from Column B and Column C and gives the result in Column D. Here, when there are no cell values present in Column B and column C, the cell value in Column D should be blank.  In my instance, the cell value in Column D appears to be blank, but when i select the full range of cells that have formula in column D and copy and paste it to a different sheet/text file, it appears to have a value. How can I go around this so that, in the event that there are no values, the cell value in Column D is blank or nothing?
I have attached screenshots for better understanding.[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What value do you get when you copy and paste?

Comment: Use *Nothing* (`""`) instead of a space (`" "`). A cell containing a formula can never be blank. When you copy such a cell, the copy also cannot be blank. *Nothing* is the best you can do. You don't need to check if the cell is blank (`=IF(ISBLANK(A1),...,...)`): you can check if the cell contains *Nothing* (`=IF(A1="",...,...)`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was under the impression that a cell that has only the formula and no value in it can be considered as a blank cell. The Nothing alternative that you suggested works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot it seems you have space `" "` in true part of `IF()` formula. Better use `TEXTJOIN()` with parameter ignore blanks.

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B4:C4)
```

Comment: I'm quite new to excel formulas and vba's and this alternate formula for Concatenate was an eye opener. I noted it down and used it - it works great. Thank you very much @Harun